# Can't find resource from Bundle

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to read a file in my Bundle using the following code.

```
let bundle =  Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let path = bundle.url(forResource: "file1", withExtension: "xml")!
```

But path returns nil. I have try Bundle.main, but I get the same error.
I have added the files in the bundle by

1. drag my file to Xcode and clicks all the targets in the pop up dialog.
2. select 'copy items if needed'
3. clicks all the targets in the pop up dialog.

I tried to debug, but from the bundle object in the debugger, I can't find a property which shows me what resources it has or not.

Can you please tell me how to fix the issue?

Update:
If I manually copy the files (in Macos Finder) to this directory

```
/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject/Build/Products/Debug
```

Then, the swift code can find the file. Can you please tell me what do I need to do to add file to Main Bundle?

Comment: That's not how you get the path of a resource in the bundle.

Comment: Select the file in the project navigator, press ⌥⌘1 and check if the checkbox in Target Membership ist checked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Click the target of project.
2. Select the item of Build Phase.
3. under `Copy Bundle Resources` check if your file is listed or not. If not
   listed add with the plus button.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks. I did the step above. I see the files are copy in `/Users/hap497/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject/MyProjectTests.xctest/Contents/Resources. But the path is still nil when I look for it likes        let bundle =  Bundle(for: type(of: self))
       var path = bundle.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "json"). When I debug the code, i see teh bundle is pointing to MyProject/MyProjectTests.xctest. not Contents/Resources/